# cron job creating folder + move files

Tags: php, cron

I've got an IP camera sending images to my FTP server when triggered a motion. The problem is that it only sending the the file to the folder and it's not categorized after date.

What I need to do is to create a folder with todays date (Y M D) and as soon as the camera has sent images to the root folder of /pics a cron job will move the files to the created date folder.

How can this be done?

Thank you!

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: How can be done what __exactly__?

Comment: You can't trigger a cron job from the upload, you'd have to continually poll the root folder every minute (or longer) -- this implies a delay between the upload and the processing. You might be able to configure the camera to change its name based on date, or configure the FTP server to rename the file on write, or refer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files) question for triggered suggestions.

Comment: You can take a look at the watch command  http://beerpla.net/2007/08/04/watch-a-useful-linux-command-you-may-have-never-heard-of/

Comment: Looks like a job for a bash script and [incrontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)

Comment: You've given us no code; we don't do things from scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example